# RabbitMq: Disabling prefetching (prefetch_count=0) with auto-ack=false

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Is it possible to disable prefetching with auto-ack=false? I just want to avoid reading message (prefetching) from a queue every time I acknowledge a message. I want to read a message only when I call a 'consume_message'. Setting prefetch_count=0 seems doesn't work and it's treated as 'no specif limit'.

UPDATED:
As I understand 'prefetch_count' is the number of messages cached on the client side (read locally into buffers). For example there is a use case:

*(let's assume there is a queue we connect to and it has messages)*

1. Create a connection.
2. Set *Basic.Qos* (prefetch_count=1)
3. Start consuming *Basic.Consume*
4. Due to the prefetch_count=1 one message is already **transferred to the client** and ready to be read and marked as **not-ack'd**.
5. **Reading message** and then processing it.
6. Then the message is **ack'd**. And everything starts from **step 4**.

I thought that setting prefetch_count to 0 would avoid the step 4 and a message is transferred only when you read it - no caching on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefetch and auto-acknowledgment are not related like that. Prefetch count is simply a number of **unacknowledged** messages prepared to be delivered to a specific consumer.

Let's say you set prefetch count to N. If you set auto-ack to true, these means that these N messages are ACKed upon receiving. If you set it to false, this means that you still get the N messages but they're not ACKed until you manually ACK them.

For the last part - try setting prefetch_count to 1.

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699727/what-is-the-difference-between-prefetch-count-vs-no-ack-in-rabbitmq) and both answers.

Comment: Hm... The documentation says [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html): 'The prefetch-count is ignored if the no-ack option is set.' And it's not clear now - how many messages are consumed by a client?

Comment: The thing you suggested me (auto-ack=false and prefetch_count=1) is exactly the use case of my updated part of the question. But the key point is the step 4. which I want to avoid. Setting prefetch-count to 0 doesn't work -  it means no count specified. I hope it's clear.